# How can I prevent Devise from redirecting to login upon ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess from another api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the following controller code, line **[A]** will display the error to user (what I want), but line **[B]** results in Devise re-directing to login. Since the user *is* logged in, this culminates in display of the home page with no sign of error.

(Authentication of the third party api occasionally expires, requiring a manual step to refresh.)

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    raise StandardError, "Error accessing Shopify API: Unauthorized" #[A] (behaves as desired)
    begin
      @product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess
      raise StandardError, "Error accessing Shopify API: Unauthorized" #[B] (devise redirects to login)
    end
  end

end
```

How can I make **[B]** *not* redirect to login?

Comment: I discovered that I can do `raise StandardError, "Error accessing Shopify API: Unauthorized", cause: nil`, but is there a way to tell devise/warden **not** to handle `ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess`?

Comment: Sorry this is off topic but how are you using Devise with Shopify API? Can we talk possibly?

Comment: @uno we don't have SSO, we just have an extra login step to get the devise credentials (we don't expire logins for two weeks to make that less annoying). We are shopify plus, so we are able to link the devise user to a shopify user, but the oauth setup of the `shopify_app` gem would require a lot of wrangling to integrate with shopify SSO & have per-shopify-user sessions in the app.